# Comparing enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a DTO with enum type. I wan to test DTO field but not sure how can I do it.

```
Class MyDto {
  public enum ExamResult { PASS, FAIL };
  private ExamResult result;
  ...
}
```

I am trying to test the result field in some other class

```
if(myDto.result.equals("PASS")) {
  //doSomething
} else {
  //doOtherthing
}
```

But .equals() always returing me false even it have correct value. So not sure how can I test it.

Comment: you need to override equals in yoru `class MyDto{}`

Comment: You are using .equals with a String type. Simple use == for two enum type comparison

Comment: @hagubear not true, you don't need to override equals. See answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing for equality `Enums` values act as if they are integers. There-for you should use the `==` operator. Although `equals(ExamResult.PASS)` also works fine as mentioned in the comments (But this is not very often used).

```
if(myDto.result == ExamResult.PASS) {
  //Do something
} else {
  //Do other thing
}
```

If you only have access to a `String` representation of the `Enum` value you could use this type of code: (But I don't recommend it)

```
if(myDto.result.getName().equals("PASS")) {
  //Do something
} else {
  //Do other thing
}
```

**More explanation:** `Enum` values are given a unique integer value at compile time. In the Java language Enum values are guaranteed to be unique in name and compile time number. You can get an Enum unique number using the `ordinal()` method. The values of Enums can be get as an array representation using the `values()` method. The name of an Enum value can be get as a String representation using the `name()` method.

Comment: How exactly are enums and `byte`/`char`/`short` (all *other* primitive types) related ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu They're not really related.  The reason you can use `==` on enums is that the language guarantees that there will be exactly one object of each enum (i.e. there's a `PASS` object and a `FAIL` object, and no other object of the class can ever be created, I think).

Comment: To even further explain this: Enums are in memory just like Integer types. Each enum value has it's own unique number. You can even get this number in Java using the ordinal method.

Comment: The `ordinal()` method does not make an `enum` some kind of `int`, the same as the `values()` method does not make it an Array and the `name()` method does not make it a String. It's a special data type for building predefined sets of constants (and you can build such a data type yourself without using the `enum` keyword -- except for the ability to `switch` your constants as `case`s).

Comment: Correct! I'm just trying to explain it all a little simple ;)

Comment: I'm all for simplicity; I'm just arguing that your answer is a bit misleading: it makes the Java enums seem very much like the C ones.

Comment: Enums are not primitives. The Java language does not treat them as if they were integers. The `name()` method provides a String name from a Java enum constant.

Comment: They don't. The `java.lang.Enum#equals()` method is declared `final` and performs an `==` test internally. That's why you can safely use `==` (which will always act the same as `equals()` for enums) -- *not* because they act like `int`s or `short`s; you're comparing object references here.

Comment: This answer still contains several errors. A more complete and correct answer is provided by the combination of the answers provided by myself and Costi Ciudatu.

Answer (score 2):

You *may* test for equality with the `==` operator. Although the enum constants are objects, there is exactly one instance of each.

[JLS 8.9: Enum constants:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) *Because there is only one instance of each enum constant, it is permitted to use the == operator in place of the equals method when comparing two object references if it is known that at least one of them refers to an enum constant.*

```
    if ( ExamResult.PASS == myDto.result ) {
         // Do something
    }
```

You may also test for equality with the `equals()` method. (Using the constant on the left avoids a NullPointerException if the variable is null.)

```
    if ( ExamResult.PASS.equals( myDto.result )) {
         // Do something
    }
```

You may also compare against the *name* of an enum constant, which is accessed through the `name()` method.

```
    if ( myDto.result.name().equals( "PASS")) {
         // Do something
    }
```

Finally, you can also use enums in `switch` statements. With more than two enum constants, this may be more concise.

```
    switch ( myDto.result ) {
    case PASS:
        // Do something
        break;

    case FAIL:
    default:
        // Do something
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java enums can declare their own variables and methods (which can be overridden by individual constants).

Besides the options listed in @AndyThomas' answer, you may consider moving the actual logic associated with each constant within the constant itself (think about the strategy pattern).

This allows you to reuse that logic in other places in your application if needed, without the need for auxiliary utility methods, in a pure OOP style. Here's a pretty complex example of what you can do (just to get an idea about what's possible):

```
enum ExamResult {
    PASS(true) {
        // override the default behavior to do something else
        @Override public void doSomething() {
            super.doSomething();
            System.out.println("whatever");
        }
    },
    FAIL(false);

    private final boolean success;

    ExamResult(boolean success) { this.success = success }

    // you can declare this as abstract if there's no default behavior
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Success: " + success);
    }
}
```

Now, your code simply becomes:

```
myDto.result.doSomething();  // of course you need to make sure result is not null
```

If you have a String holding the exam result:

```
ExamResult.valueOf(yourString).soSomething();
```

Comment: Note: For performance I would use the valueOf method only when I need an Enum value as object. For comparing an Enum value I would use the name method because this method has way less overhead under the hood.

Comment: This approach eliminates the need for comparisons. You need to somehow end up with an instance of that enum type and then put it to work. No `if`, no `switch`; just polymorphism. As for the performance concerns, the enum type uses a cache called `enumConstantDirectory` defined in `java.lang.Class` -- so the lookup is quite fast.

Comment: +1 - Should have included this additional observation in my own answer.